# Script to run at first logon in OS X to "call home"?

Tags: macos

I sell Macs and i'm looking for a way for our security and to combat purchase fraud to have the machines phone home the first time they are booted up to show that machine has been in use at the clients IP address.

Now I know the client might set the computer up at a location other than their home and could spoof their IP (although the potential scammer wouldn't realise this system was in place so wouldn't be expecting to do this) but any system is better than no system.

In terms of privacy we'd put it in our privacy policy but of course we're not looking to collect any information from the user apart from their IP address and the script should delete once its connected to the internet for the first time.

How would users recommend the best way to do it? I have full access to the computers before hand and we already launch a script on first boot of user account to show a welcome and help guide - so we could add simple scripting there, but maybe a helper program which attempts until internet connection is first established, makes contact and deletes itself is best.

And of course we'd need a two pronged approach, a URL or API of some sort on our server that the computer connects to. Ideally the information to send would be the serial number and the IP address of the user, the MAC address could be useful too - as often if fraud has been committed the police will also check to see if the original MAC address of the system has connected via the ISP server logs.

I suppose the final piece of the puzzle would be that our logged data would somehow need to prove it was sent from that computer and not just generated ourselves in a database (eg we haven't just pretended its connected from their IP we've picked up from an e-mail address or something) i'm not sure if there would be any secure legal way to do this?

=============
Edit: Thinking of ways to make it legally binding in terms of presenting the information to the police or the courts I think the receiving server would need to be hosted and maintained by an independent third party whom you had a contract with and didn't allow you any write access to the information what so ever, all you could do is visit a website and pull up the data to pretend the evidence to the police.

(I seem to have been voted down because someone likes committing fraud?)

Comment: Surely you can get your shipping agent to require a signature on delivery?

Comment: @MarkSetchell you'd think so wouldn't you - scammers now claiming its not their signature - even though its been delivered at their address, especially if in flats. If we're talking £3000-£5000 its worth their bluff to see if they can get a refund and commit fraud that'll rarely be investigated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited to being posted to the security stack exchange site: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good point @TheDarkKnight I wasn't aware of that stack - i'll close and post it there.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into similar solutions for macbooks in the past with little luck. One thing I have found however, if you have a web server, is to create a php page in an obscure hidden directory that will capture the ip address and send an email on access. From here you can create a page specific to each computer with MAC and serial number and set this as safari's homepage in a different tab. So every time someone attempts to access the internet you will be notified. 
(This php page can be a simple blank page that just looks like a new tab, or can even display warnings such as "You are being tracked")

You could also create a python script on startup to send the information you are looking for such as ip, mac and serial number back, but again you would need another server setup as a listener.

And lastly, if possible, create a business account in icloud and use Find My Iphone/mac. This is probably the easiest if you can get away with it but unfortunately will not provide you with instant notifications.

-M

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I would have no problem running a server to record the data - the problem is I don't think in terms of a legal investigation or with the police I can prove the information recorded in my database has come from the computer and hasn't just been fabricated by myself. Its a tricky one really.

Maybe installing something like prey etc would be better - but I don't really want to install extra software on buyers computers who are not fraudsters (most of them!)